# How to validate type "target.dataset" attribute of input tag in typescript

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

"dataset" attribute is always disallowed HTMLInputElement.

I searched the document of [DOM types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L5271). There is no "data" or "dataset" anywhere.

Of course, it's possible to use "non-null" type likes below "variables key" in changeLoginValue.

```
export interface LoginForm {
    id: string;
    password: string;
    [key: string]: string;
}

export interface ILoginStore {
    loginValue: LoginForm;
    changeLoginValue(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void;
}

class LoginStore implements ILoginStore {
    @observable loginValue: LoginForm = {
        id: '',
        password: '',
    }

    @action.bound changeLoginValue(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void {
        const key = e.target.dataset.name!;
        this.loginValue[key] = e.target.value;
    }
}
```

It nicely works in application.

But it seems a some tricky way in typescript and the most important thing is that it always fail to compile in jest.

my test code is

```
import LoginStore from './loginStore';

describe('LoginStore', () => {
    it('change id and password in loginValue', () => {
        const event = {
            target: {
                dataset: {
                    name: 'id',
                },
                value: 'abcdef',
            },
          } as React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>;

        LoginStore.changeLoginValue(event);

        expect(LoginStore.loginValue.id).toBe('abcdef');
    })
})
```

It show typescript error when declare "const event":

#### Conversion of type '{ target: { dataset: { name: string; }; value: string; }; }' to type 'ChangeEvent' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.

Type '{ target: { dataset: { name: string; }; value: string; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ChangeEvent': nativeEvent, currentTarget, bubbles, cancelable, and 10 more.ts(2352) ###

How to use "dataset" attribute?
Do I have to make custom interface for this?

I'm using

```
"babel-jest": "^24.5.0",
"jest": "^24.5.0",
"typescript": "^3.4.1"
"ts-jest": "^24.0.1",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event` is a mock of a `React.ChangeEvent`.

It will never match the expected type (it's not going to implement `nativeEvent`, `currentTarget`, `bubbles`, `cancelable`, etc.).

For situations like these where you know your mock doesn't match the expected type and you want TypeScript to let it through anyway you can use the [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any) type...

> ...to opt-out of type checking and let the values pass through compile-time checks.

---

```ts
const event: any = {  // <= use 'any' for the mock
  target: {
    dataset: {
      name: 'id',
    },
    value: 'abcdef',
  },
};
```

Comment: thanks very much. I fully understood your answer but don't want to use 'any'....so now I gave up to use 'dataset' and used 'name' attribute. Thanks again but sorry I can not vote your answer because of lack of stackoverflow reputation.